# How to input ListBox items from server side code asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

I have a list box on a page and i am looking to show within the listbox a list of usernames from a group/global session when the page loads so the info is automatically filled in.

I have started or tried to start to write a function that will fill in the listbox but i am very unsure about what needs to be entered in the middle or if any of it is correct.

The data that i would like the box to show is pulled from Global Sessions as shown below;

```
Session("AdminGroup") = "myapp_it_admin"
Sesssion("ReadOnlyGroup") = "myapp_it_readonly"
Session("ReadWriteGroup") = "myapp_it_readwrite"
```

My .aspx code;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/UserMast.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Admin.aspx.vb" Inherits="Admin" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div id="sListBox">

    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="289px" Width="211px"></asp:ListBox>


  </div>

</asp:Content>
```

My aspx.vb code;

```
Public Function ListBoxFill() As String

    Dim answer As String = ""

    If Page.IsPostBack Then

        ListBox1.??SOMETHING()??

    End If


    Return answer
End Function
```

Please let me know if i have missed anything or if you need any more details. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a VB dev so syntax may be iffy but maybe something like this : -

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles MyBase.Load

If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then

    ListBox1.Items.Add(New ListItem("myapp_it_admin", "AdminGroup"))
    ListBox1.Items.Add(New ListItem("myapp_it_readwrite", "ReadOnlyGroup"))

End If

End Sub
```